# checkbox not displaying check mark correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react form that gets the status of a checkbox element from local storage with `useEffect`.

```
const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setCheckbox(localStorage.getItem('Checkbox Value'))
},[]);
```

The JSX is

```
<div className="ui checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleCheckboxChange} checked={checkbox}</input>
   <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions: {checkbox}</label>
</div>
```

When the form renders the correct value (true, false) displays in the label
but the checkbox renders checked no matter what the value
Not sure what I am missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage always returns strings, and since "false" (string) is a truthy value, your checkbox will be always checked.

Change your code to be:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  setCheckbox(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Checkbox Value') || 'false'))
},[]);
```

Comment: would you mind to mark is at the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, thank you for the answer